# SQL - Make an id start with a number depending on the entity type

Tags: mysql, sql, database, entity-model

In my database I have a User table. I don't represent this in the database but in the implementation of the application I'm working on, there are two types of Users (let's say an A type and a B type).

What I want to do is make the id of an A type user start with a 1 (for example idUser=1016) and a B type user id to start with a 2 (for example idUser=2634).

Is this possible? I've been trying to do this through AUTO_INCREMENT but I'm not too sure how to go about this idea.

Comment: Regret to say this is a bad idea, you certainly will not achieve it through an auto-increment column (the "auto" is just that: automatic & not under your control). Much better to have a separate column that indicates type (ps: who know one day there may be a need for more types). btw: what would happen if a user changes type?

Comment: You're probably right, I might as well just add an ENUM type column. There are only two types in the application and a user cannot change types anyway so...

Comment: I share UBA's concerns, but not their regrets.